# Clarification on nonce collision calculation

Tags: collision-resistance, nonce, aes-gcm

I've been working on a AES256-GCM implementation (in Java).
I'm a little bit stuck on the part where i need to decide how often i need to rotate my key.

I've got a lot of information from this posts:
[Safety of random nonce with AES-GCM?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42982/safety-of-random-nonce-with-aes-gcm)

And the website if refers to: https://www.imperialviolet.org/2015/05/16/aeads.html

It states the following quote:

> This is because if you throw 2$^{32}$ balls at 2$^{96}$ buckets then you have roughly a 2$^{-33}$ chance of getting two in the same bucket.

How is this calculation done?
The only solution i can think about is:

2$^{(95-128)}$=2$^{-33}$

I would like to know the following:

1. Is this the correct calculation?
2. Is the 2$^{95}$ chosen, because only 50% is needed and 2$^{96}$ / 2 = 2$^{95}$
3. Subtracting by 128 refers to the total length of the IV or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that it's a significantly more complex calculation based on the mathematics of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_of_a_shared_birthday_(collision)). Per the link, if we throw $n$ balls into $d$ buckets then the probability $p(n;d)$ of a collision is approximately
$$p(n;d)\approx 1-\exp\left(-\frac{n(n-1)}{2d}\right)= \frac{n(n-1)}{2d}+O\left(\frac{n^4}{d^2}\right)$$
(the second approximation following from the [Taylor series for $\exp(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function)).

Plugging in $n=2^{32}$ and $d=2^{96}$ gives $p\approx 2^{-33}$. More generally if $n=2^a$ and $d=2^b$ we will have $p\approx 2^{2a-b-1}$ provided that $2a$ noticeably less than $b$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Appending this comment, hit enter to soon after saying thanks and formatting takes some time.

I was calculating a bit different, according to these posts:


 - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883983/birthday-paradox-huge-numbers

 - https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

It gives the same result with the rule you mentioned: $a^2 < b$

The simplified version in those links was: 
$$
\frac{a^2}{2b}
$$

With my values:
$$
\frac{{(2^{32}})^{2}}{2 \cdot 2^{96}} = \frac{1}{2^{33}} = 2^{-33}
$$